# what happens to an active HTTP call if the Activity that it is running in is closed?

Tags: android, multithreading, apache-commons

I'm using Apache Commons to make my HTTP calls, and in my activity I have a thread that makes the call.  If a call is made by a device and is sitting there waiting to connect (imagine that the network is congested and the call is taking some time) and in the mean time, the user exits the app and the Activity is backgrounded.  What happens to my call? For that matter (come to think of it) what happens to any thread that was started within the activity? If I have a thread that's sitting there and doing its thing (whatever it is) and the activity is closed, do I have to handle killing the thread myself onPause()?

Edit...
So, given Ted Hopp's answer, what is the right way to kill the Apache request?  I'm looking through the [Commons documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnection.html) and there are a bunch of methods that *look like they would do the trick, but since the doc is so lacking in details (why even bother with a doc if you're not going to specify things?!) I'm wondering which of those methods I should call on my HttpConnection object before killing the thread that my connection is sitting in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing an activity has no direct effect on the process in which the activity is hosted. All other threads continue running. You should override one or more of the [life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle) methods (`onPause`, `onDestroy`, etc.) to detect that the activity is finishing and interrupt or otherwise terminate running threads. The activity method `isFinishing()` is useful for distinguishing between an activity being shut down and one that is being destroyed and restarted due to a configuration change.

Your thread should be written with a method to cancel execution. With apache-commons in particular, that method should have two steps. First, you should call `abort()` for the method that you passed to your `HttpClient.execute()` method. Second, you should close the connection itself:

```
client.getHttpConnectionManager()
    .getConnection(client.getHostConfiguration()).close();
```

Actually, if you do just the last step, that should actually suffice to throw an `IOException` in the method and stop everything.

Comment: Awesome... so then to ask the specifics of my Apache question, how do I go about killing the HTTP request?

Comment: If the thread is blocking on a network request it is best to just let it run its course instead of actively trying to kill the thread or HTTP request. Not only are you saving the app from grief but possibly the server too. Just make sure your thread exits gracefully after it returns from an HTTP request to find the Activity is gone.

Comment: @Barry Fruitman, I hear you, but in my specific case, I really don't want the server to silently get hit eventually by a lagging request.  If it's not going to have a client to respond to, I would rather it just didn't get through.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - I edited my answer to provide specifics for Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0):

Google strongly advises developers not to make HTTP calls in an `Activity`. `Service` is the recommended model. Android apps are going to be paused for many, many reasons. Some of the most common are to answer a call, sms or email. I doubt that you want to cancel the call, and therefore have the user wait for it again when he/she returns, when it could all happen in the background.

The best option is to use a `Service` or `IntentService` to make the call and persist the data (perhaps into an SQLite database). When the `Activity` is resumed, it can simply check for new entries in the database.

If you haven't already seen it, check out the "[Developing Android REST Client Applications](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html)" from Google I/O 2010. Be sure to notice the PDF download link.

Comment: thanks, I'm actually aware of all this, but unfortunately, in this particular case need the call to be made by the activity, and in fact, the user's departure is the very thing that needs to kill the connection if one is in mid transit. It's important that in most cases the response NOT get swallowed by a service reaction, as the same user is not going to come back (this is a custom app for a kiosk application that will be used by large numbers of disperate users).  So, while I agree with the premise of your general argument, it doesn't apply to my case.